# Dedekind cut containing one element

Tags: calculus

What would be an example of an ordered set, let's call it D, such that D is a Dedekind cut and D is a singleton set?

Comment: What makes you think that there is such a thing? And what definition of "Dedekind cut" are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided more information. Here is an excerpt from a text that I'm reading:  
Dedekind cuts were defined as subsets of the set Q. However, an examination of this definition reveals that it does not make use of the full features of Q, but only the order relation < on Q. Hence, it is possible to define Dedekind cuts on sets equipped with only order relations, but not necessarily with binary operations such as addition and multiplication. Let S be a non-empty ordered set. 
The Dedekind set of S, denoted S^D, is defined by,
S^D = {A ⊆ S | A is a Dedekind cut}.

Comment: Maybe try $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$.  Then $\{0\}$ perhaps is a "Dedekind cut"?  I cannot really tell, since you did not give the definition of "Dedekind cut" or your textbook.

Comment: @GEdgar. Sincere apologies for not providing complete information. The textbook in question is "Real numbers and Real analysis by Ethan D. Block". Specifically, exercise 1.7.8 (2) on page 51. Here is result from a quick google search regarding the textbook: https://muhammadalfaridzi.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/the_real_numbers_and_real_analysis.pdf.
I'm hoping they have a license to share Mr. Block's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the clarification, consider the set $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$, with the usual order. Then $A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{3\}$ is a Dedekind cut if your definition is "a Dedekind cut is a partition of $S$ into sets $A$ and $B$ with every element of $A$ less than every element of $B$." In the case of the rationals, one makes the additional requirement that $A$ has no maximal element, but $B$ may have a minimal element. (With that condition, a 1-element set $A$ is impossible!). Of course, we don't really need the set $A$: once we know $B$, we have $A = S - B$. So perhaps your text defines a Dedekind cut as a set $B$, possibly with a minimal element, and having the property that every element of $B$ is greater than every element of the complement of $B$. If so, then in my example, the set $B$ is a one-element Dedekind cut.

To see why I'm hedging a little here, consider the description given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut. In that formulation, a Dedekind-cut is a *pair* of sets rather than a single set, so I'm having to guess what your 'one-set' definition might be.

Comment: And having looked at the text, I see that my guess (tjat the author's Dedekind cut is the "B" part of a usual Dedekind cut) was correct. So my answer (by blind luck) is correct.